# Emulator don't jobs correctly with dps

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a simple layout, that have one button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

I want to see that the button scale correctly in different densities. I created three emulators, with different abstracted lcd density (120,160 and 240).

When I run the application in the tree emulators, the button size is bigger in each emulator. If I read the hight and width of button in pixels I can see that the size is right.

Is there a problem with the density in the emulator?

The version of Android is ICS.

Thank you very much.

**Edit.**

I upload some images about the problem.  The first images are in 160 densities and the seconds have 240.

[screen_with_160_screen_home](https://picasaweb.google.com/101173880172485002884/Captures_android#5751170683038901490)
[screen_with_240_screen_home](https://picasaweb.google.com/101173880172485002884/Captures_android#5751170705021518370)

You can see that all the elements ara bigger in the 240, even the home screen.

Comment: You need to read this [page: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I read that page, so I think the problem may be in the emulator, but I don't know if I'm wrong setting.

Comment: Sorry, that page was not found.

Comment: Sorry, it's true. The images were private are now public. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

//according to the density it will differ when you use the dp or dip

```
if 200dp in 120 dpi=200×120÷160=150px
if 200dp in 160 dpi=200×160÷160=200px
if 200dp in 240 dpi=200×240÷160=300px
```

this `dp/dip` will auto scale

if you want fixed size mean you need to use the `px`

[Best Practices:](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence)

Comment: That are the sizes that application return me. But, I think that the button should take the same size in all densitys, because, there are most pixels in hight densitys. I noticed that the home screen is also displayed without scaled. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not getting you, did you read the best practice link. For instance, a view with a layout_width="100dp" measures 100 pixels wide on medium-density screen and the system scales it up to 150 pixels wide on high-density screen, so that the view occupies approximately the same physical space on the screen.

Comment: I edited the question and I upload two images, to try to explayn the problem.